# i am passing data from android to unity and based on the name it sets the state active of that object. But i keep geting game object null reference

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

here I have exported project and created an aar file and imported in the android studio and my android studio simply passes an intent to unity player activity on a button click. but I keep getting the game object as null. What could be the problem? 
this doesn't even work when I set the object manually and set it to true and run in unity only.. it doesn't even print debug.log();

Here i am using vuforia ground plane detection and my object is kitchen stool and i am placing it inside ground plane stage.
and the script is in ar camera.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

     public class data : MonoBehaviour
{
   // private Transform childObj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
        bool hasExtra = intent.Call<bool>("hasExtra", "arguments");
        if (hasExtra)
        {
          AndroidJavaObject extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
         string arguments = extras.Call<string>("getString", "arguments");
         GameObject g = GameObject.Find(arguments);
         g.SetActive(true);
         Debug.Log("hello");
         }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .Find() to find a gameobject that is inactive in your scene. You can either assign the object up front in the inspector or use [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html). Alternatively, make the object the child of an empty gameobject, and use transform.GetChild(0) to toggle its state.

Comment: now I've changed my script I've declared a public variable game object and assigned a stool there by dragging and dropping, and it sets to active state but it doesn't display on the ground plane ... why is ground plane not accurate.

Comment: so did you find a solution?